# Having a GET request inside a mailto body

Tags: html, get, mailto

i'm trying to parse some arguments inside the body of a mailto but it is cutting after the '&' on the argument itself

```
<a href='mailto:?subject=foo&body="bar https://www.website.com/index.php?op1=firstarg&op2=secarg"'>Enviar e-mail</a>
```

After the "firstarg" on the link nothing shows up on the e-mail body.

Is there any way that i can overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: Parsing how? - please show code - this needs to be URIencoded too: `body="bar https://w....`

Comment: I showed the code there, it's all i got so far

Comment: _I’m trying to parse_ - where and with what? Server? JavaScript?

Comment: I want to parse a code inside the url sent by e-mail, but by using the '&' character it cuts out the rest of the parameters from the body

Comment: You are not at all answering my question. Parsing the URL with WHAT? PHP? JavaScript? COBOL?

Comment: You need to send `<a href='mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=foo&body=bar%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Findex.php%3Fop1%3Dfirstarg%26op2%3Dsecarg'>Enviar e-mail</a>`

Comment: From html with mailto to php but that fixed it. Thanks a lot!